# Classifying texts using pre-trained DistilBERT transformer on Multiple GPUS

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I have a pre-trained DistilBERT transformer to classify the texts in the `user_posts_cat` col:

```py
user_agg = pd.DataFrame({"user_username": ["user1", "user2"], 
                         "user_posts_cat": [
                                           ["Stackoverflow Community is Great", "Sample Text"],
                                           ["I Love Transformers", "Sample Text 2", "Test"],
                                           ]}).set_index("user_username")
```

I am currently using the following code to identify whether a user in `user_agg`'s index above is a bot, using the most common predicted labels from a user's posts:

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

def load_nlp(directory_path, num_labels=2, gpu_index="cuda:0"):
    device = torch.device(gpu_index if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    tokenizer_ = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(directory_path)
    model_ = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        directory_path, num_labels=num_labels).to(device)

    pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model=model_, tokenizer=tokenizer_, device=device.index)

    return pipe

saved_model_local_path = "model_path"
pipe = load_nlp(saved_model_local_path, num_labels=2)

from collections import Counter

def label_cls(posts, pipe=pipe) -> str:
    labels = pipe(posts, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512, add_special_tokens=True)
    most_common_label = Counter([item["label"] for item in labels]).most_common(1)[0][0]
    return most_common_label

user_agg["user_label"] = [label_cls(posts) for posts in user_agg.user_posts_cat]
user_agg["user_label"] = np.where(user_agg.user_label == "LABEL_1", "bot", "human")
```

The code above uses only single GPU. I want to run the above predictions on all of my four GPUs. I have tried using the `torch.nn.DataParallel` module but failed with an error indicating that `DataParallel does not have the config attribute` from the transformers module.

I am using:

```py
python: 3.10.2
CUDA: 12.0
A100 40GB X4 - Driver: 525.105.17
pandas: 2.0.0
keras: 2.11.0
torch: 1.13.1
transformers: 4.30.2
```